# How to make ubuntu as the second Operating System

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, debian, console

So, I installed Debian (my dad installed it, i dont know, i am just 13), 2 months ago and after that installed Ubuntu (I installed it!!!) alongside debian by re-sizing the partition. Now, the Ubuntu is in the first option and the second  one is debian. (I REGULARLY USE DEBIAN). I want debian to be the first one choice

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the GRUB config file, but I recommend you use Grub Customizer:

https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

You can change the default build in the "General Settings" tab and set a timeout so you don't have to hit enter.  Use 0 if you don't want GRUB to display by default.

Secondly, if you want your entry to be in the first position you can move it up in the "List Configuration" tab.

If you would like to manually change the configuration file and not download this application then read this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto/ChangeDefaultOS)

Just realize you must run "sudo update-grub" to apply any changes you make if you edit the configuration file which is not included in that link.

Comment: i downloaded this software but the debian is already in the first option and ubuntu is in the third option, what to do now?

Comment: Well I would try 2 things.  First thing I'd check is if there are multiple Debian entries and move all them before Ubuntu.  I see that often there are multiple entries and I move the wrong one. Second thing I'd try is looking in the config file and checking what the actual order is. Don't save changes until you fully understand it, but that's the truth data.  What's in there is what your Grub displays.